# How to determine where a tarball expanded

Tags: rhel, tar

I ran the following on Redhat linux:

```
tar zxvf jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

resulting in:

```
jdk1.7.0_79/
jdk1.7.0_79/LICENSE
jdk1.7.0_79/release
jdk1.7.0_79/jre/
jdk1.7.0_79/jre/LICENSE
jdk1.7.0_79/jre/Welcome.html
jdk1.7.0_79/jre/plugin/
jdk1.7.0_79/jre/plugin/desktop/
jdk1.7.0_79/jre/plugin/desktop/sun_java.png
jdk1.7.0_79/jre/plugin/desktop/sun_java.desktop
jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/
jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/fontconfig.SuSE.10.properties.src
jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/alt-rt.jar
jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/meta-index
jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/net.properties
...
```

But I don't know where all these files were expanding to.

How do I determine where the files and folders went?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They went to whatever was your current directory when you ran `tar`; if you haven't closed the terminal or changed directories since,

```
pwd
```

will tell you where they are.

Answer (score 1):

You can search the filesystem for one of those paths, for example (it can take a while):

```
find / -path "*/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/Welcome.html"
```

The output could be:

```
/path/to/unpacked/tarball/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/Welcome.html
```

The place would then be `/path/to/unpacked/tarball/`